# Can't find HttpContext in .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, httpcontext

I used code from [here](http://www.akamarketing.com/blog/256-csv-datatable.html) and I get the following error:
    Can't use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()`

In Visual Studio 2008 does the ContextMenuEntry "Solve" help you when you have missing references?

I already found out that `HttpContext` is not a member of `System.Web` in my IDE. 
According to Help > Info I am using .NET 3.5 SP1.

How do I get that running?

How do u usually react in this situation? What stuff do u look for in msdn.com?

Comment: Thank you all for the fast and highly qualitive answers, especially Timwi and Guffa!

Comment: I Now always use ReSharper from JetBrains to "solve" These Problems (as answered by David Culp). With this Addon you can add to Visual Studio features that are common sense in Eclipse.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What I would do in that situation is look on MSDN (or Google) for `HttpContext`. I did that, and it says it’s in `System.Web`. So make sure your project has a reference to `System.Web`.

[image: “Add Reference” menu item]

[image: “System.Web” in the Add Reference dialog]

... and then it seems to work:

[image: HttpContext is now available.]

Comment: You rock! Thanks for the screen cast ;)

I thought typing "Using System.Web" is enough. Maybe I have to go though this menu to set using directives. OR the IDE did not recognize the copied code. 

Magic somehow, because nothing changed in my file ;)

Comment: @user: If Timwi helped you out, be sure to mark this as an answer. Do note that assembly references and using statements are different animals. Assembly references determine what code is available for your application to consume. Namespace using statements provide only convenient shorthand for referring to classes without their full namespace-qualified name. You'll find that adding references will change only your csproj/vbproj file.

Comment: @user433718: In addition to what @kbrimington said above, also let me point out that the assembly’s name is not always the same as the namespace name (which makes it very confusing). For example, a lot of the WPF stuff is in the assembly *PresentationCore* but in the namespace *System.Windows.Media*.

Comment: @kbrimington: I didn't knew that before I reconized the OK-Button now. I wanted to rate it up, but that was disabled for me. So, Im gonna close this question now as answered.

Thanks for clearifying the issue in the last two comments!

Answer (score 2):

You can look in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) for the HttpContext class, and it tells you that it's in the `System.Web` namespace, in the `System.Web.dll` library.

So, to use it you need a reference to the `System.Web.dll` library, and you either need a `using System.Web;` statement, or use the fullly qualified name `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`.

However, are you sure that you want to use the `MapPath` method? The method gets the physical path of a web reference to a file. If the path to your CSV file is a web reference, for example `"/data/items.csv"` then you want to use the `MapPath` method, but if you have a physical path like for example `"C:\mydata\items.csv"` then you don't want to convert it.

Also, the `MapPath` only works if you actually are in a web application, where there is a HTTP context.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I will look into that. I didnt know that before. Just wanted to get it working somehow...

Comment: Yep, I even dont need this Code! *lol* Thank you! I'm sure this would have been my next question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Timwi has it right, but for completeness.  No, VS does not have the 'Solve' capability built in, however this functionality has been partially added by some add-ons.  For example, Resharper will add the option to add the reference and using when needed -- but it does have to have been referenced before in the solution so it doesn't solve the initial find problem.

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple case of not using the right framework, by that I mean the full fat version rather than the default 'light' version.

Right click on the Project and then Properties and make sure the full version of the latest framework is selected ie '.NET Framework 4', not '.NET Framework 4 Client Profile'

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a reference to `System.Web` in your project.

`HttpContext` is a member of `System.Web`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx

Comment: I already had "Using System.Web"

But when I try to type "Using System.Web.HttpContext" it says "HttpContext" not found in the namespace "System.Web"

I also tried "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()" in the code. At this point Visual Studio said again "not in the namespace..."

Comment: @user433718: You can't put `HttpContext` in your `using` statement, as it's a class, not a namespace.

Comment: The IDE can't automatically detect the namespace if the DLL is not referenced. If you want to be able to do that even with not referenced DLL's, I don't think it's possible.